# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery on laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4

hello guys after mixing laravel template i have some problem with the jquery with Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

and after searcing im still confused whats happen can you help me

here is my code :

```
<script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/ace-extra.min.js')}}}"></script>
<script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}}"></script>
  <script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/ace-elements.min.js')}}}"></script>
  <script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/ace.min.js')}}}"></script>
```

`

and error on firefox :

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR0rD.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture.  Paste it as text and format it as code using the button for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap JS works with some jQuery elements.

You need to import jQuery before importing Bootstrap JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Then import bootstrap js -->
```

Comment: thanks @zooly its work :)

Comment: Nice !
You can mark answer as right and I wish you good luck in your dev work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have not included [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) into your HTML. Download that, and include it before bootstrap.